# TCP multi client server Program

Tags: c, linux, sockets, tcp

I am making a tcp multiple client server chat room. My code for TCP multiple clients server and client is attached along with. I am unable to add another feature to my program i.e, client removal. Show the idle client can be removed from the server’s list. For example if a client is idle for 30 seconds it should be removed by server.

Please help me with that. here is the server program

```
 /* to compile me in Linux, type:  gcc -o server t1.c -lpthread */  
 /* t1.c - code for server program that uses TCP/IP */  
 /****SERVER CODE****/  
 #include <stdio.h>            
 #include <stdlib.h>            
 #include <sys/socket.h>          //for sockets  
 #include <sys/types.h>            
 #include <string.h>          //for string operations  
 #include <netinet/in.h>          //Internet Protocol family sockaddr_in defined here   
 #include <pthread.h>          // for the cosy POSIX threads  
 #include <arpa/inet.h>          // for inet_ntoa() function  
 #include <unistd.h>          //NULL constant defined here  
 #include <signal.h>          //for ctrl+c signal  
 #define BACKLOG 100          // connections in the queue  
 #define MAXDATALEN 256           //max size of messages to be sent  
 #define PORT 2012          //default port number  
 /*Note:  The port argument is optional. If no port is specified,  
  *     the server uses the default given by PORT.*/  
   struct Node                         /*structure to handle all clients*/  
     {  
       int port;  
        char username[10];  
       struct Node *next;  
     };  
   typedef struct Node *ptrtonode;  
   typedef ptrtonode head;  
   typedef ptrtonode addr;  
      void sendtoall(char *,int new_fd);     /*send chat msgs to all connected clients*/  
      void Quitall( );               /*send msg to all if server shuts down*/  
      head MakeEmpty( head h );          /*clearing list*/  
      void Delete( int port, head h );     /*delete client values on client exit*/  
      void Insert(int port,char*,head h,addr a);/*inserting new client */  
      void DeleteList( head h );          /*clearing list*/  
      void Display( const head h );          /*list all clients connected*/  
      void *Quitproc( );                /*signal handler*/  
      void *server(void * arg);          /*server instance for every connected client*/  
      void zzz();  
      char      username[10];          /*size of username*/  
      int sf2;  
      head h;                    /*variable of type struct head*/  
      char     buffer[MAXDATALEN];  
      /******main starts ***********/  
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {  
      int       sockfd,new_fd;                /*variables for socket*/  
      int      portnum;               /*variable for port numb if provided*/  
      struct sockaddr_in      server_addr;     /*structure to hold server's address */  
      struct sockaddr_in      client_addr;     /*structure to hold client's address */  
      int      cli_size,z;               /*length of address */  
      pthread_t      thr;               /*variable to hold thread ID */  
      int      yes=1;  
       addr a;                         /*variable of type struct addr*/  
      printf("\n\t*-*-*-*SERVER STARTED*-*-*-*\n");  
      /*=optional or default port argument=*/  
  if( argc == 2 )       
       portnum = atoi(argv[1]);  
  else   
      portnum = PORT; //if port number not given as argument then using default port  
      printf("PORT NO.:\t%d\n",portnum);  
      h = MakeEmpty( NULL );          //frees the list  
      /*=set info of server =*/  
      server_addr.sin_family=AF_INET;          /* set family to Internet   */  
      server_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); /* set IP address */  
      server_addr.sin_port=htons(portnum);  
       printf("IP ADDRESS:\t%s\n",inet_ntoa(server_addr.sin_addr));  
      /*=creating socket=*/  
      sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);  
   if(sockfd == -1){  
      printf("server- socket() error");     // debugging  
      exit(1);  
   }else  
      printf("socket\t\tcreated.\n");  
   if (setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes,sizeof(int)) == -1) {  
      printf("setsockopt error");     // debugging  
      exit(1);  
   }else printf("reusing\t\tport\n");  
      /*=binding socket=*/  
   if(bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr))==-1){  
           printf("binding failed\n");     // debugging  
      exit(1);}  
   else   
      printf("binding\t\tsuccess.\n\n");  
 printf("\t\tPRESS CTRL+z TO VIEW ONLINE CLIENTS\n\n");  
      /*=socket on listening mode=*/  
      listen(sockfd, BACKLOG);  
      printf("waiting for clients......\n");  
   if (signal(SIGINT,(void *)Quitproc)==0)     //signal handler  
   if(signal(SIGTSTP, zzz)==0)               //signal handler  
   while(1){  
             cli_size=sizeof(struct sockaddr_in); //cli_size necessary as an argument for pthread_create  
             new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr,&cli_size); //accepting connection from client   
             a =h ;  
           /*=sign in with name=*/  
           bzero(username,10);            
           if(recv(new_fd,username,sizeof(username),0)>0);  
             username[strlen(username)-1]=':';  
             printf("\t%d->%s JOINED chatroom\n",new_fd,username);  
             sprintf(buffer,"%s IS ONLINE\n",username);  
             Insert( new_fd,username, h, a );               //inserting newly accepted client socked fd in list  
             a = a->next;  
           /*=notify all clients about newly joining clients=*/   
             a = h ;  
           do{  
             a = a->next;  
             sf2 = a->port;  
           if(sf2!=new_fd)  
           send(sf2,buffer ,sizeof(buffer),0);  
           } while( a->next != NULL );  
              printf("server got connection from %s & %d\n\n",inet_ntoa(client_addr.sin_addr),new_fd); // debugging  
            struct Node args;                          //struct to pass multiple arguments to server function  
             args.port=new_fd;  
             strcpy(args.username,username);  
            pthread_create(&thr,NULL,server,(void*)&args);      //creating thread for every client connected   
            pthread_detach(thr);  
       } /*while end*/  
  DeleteList(h);                          //deleting all clients when server closes  
  close(sockfd);  
 }/********main ends***********/  
      /*******ALL FUNCTIONS DEFINED BELOW*********/  
 /* ==========Server function for every connected Client =========*/  
 void *server(void * arguments){  
  struct Node *args=arguments;  
  char     buffer[MAXDATALEN],ubuf[50],uname[10];     /* buffer for string the server sends */   
  char *strp;            
  char      *msg = (char *) malloc(MAXDATALEN);  
  int      ts_fd,x,y;  
  int      sfd,msglen;  
  ts_fd = args->port;      /*socket variable passed as arg*/  
  strcpy(uname,args->username);   
  addr      a;  
       /*=sending list of clients online=*/  
       a =h ;  
           do{  
           a = a->next;  
           sprintf( ubuf," %s is online\n",a->username );  
           send(ts_fd,ubuf,strlen(ubuf),0);  
           } while( a->next != NULL );  
       /*=start chatting=*/  
   while(1){  
        bzero(buffer,256);  
        y=recv(ts_fd,buffer,MAXDATALEN,0);  
       if (y==0)   
       goto jmp;  
        /*=if a client quits=*/  
       if ( strncmp( buffer, "quit", 4) == 0 ){  
      jmp:     printf("%d ->%s left chat deleting from list\n",ts_fd,uname);  
           sprintf(buffer,"%s has left the chat\n",uname);  
           addr a = h ;  
           do{  
                a = a->next;  
                sfd = a->port;  
                if(sfd == ts_fd)   
                 Delete( sfd, h );  
                if(sfd != ts_fd)   
                 send(sfd,buffer,MAXDATALEN,0);  
            }while ( a->next != NULL );  
                Display( h );  
                close(ts_fd);  
                free(msg);  
             break;  
            }  
      /*=sending message to all clients =*/  
      printf("%s %s\n",uname,buffer);  
      strcpy(msg,uname);  
      x=strlen(msg);  
      strp = msg;  
      strp+= x;  
      strcat(strp,buffer);  
      msglen=strlen(msg);  
        addr a = h ;  
      do{  
       a = a->next;  
       sfd = a->port;  
      if(sfd != ts_fd)   
        send(sfd,msg,msglen,0);  
      } while( a->next != NULL );  
       Display( h );  
       bzero(msg,MAXDATALEN);  
   }//end while  
    return 0;  
 }// end server  
 /*=====empties and deletes the list======*/  
 head MakeEmpty( head h )  
      {  
      if( h != NULL )  
           DeleteList( h );  
           h = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );  
      if( h == NULL )  
           printf( "Out of memory!" );  
           h->next = NULL;  
      return h;  
      }  
 /*======delete list=======*/  
 void DeleteList( head h )  
      {  
      addr a, Tmp;  
      a = h->next;   
      h->next = NULL;  
           while( a != NULL )  
           {  
           Tmp = a->next;  
           free( a );  
           a = Tmp;  
           }  
      }  
 /*===============inserting new clients to list==========*/  
 void Insert( int port,char *username, head h, addr a )  
      {  
      addr TmpCell;  
      TmpCell = malloc( sizeof( struct Node ) );  
           if( TmpCell == NULL )  
           printf( "Out of space!!!" );  
      TmpCell->port = port;  
      strcpy(TmpCell->username,username);  
      TmpCell->next = a->next;  
      a->next = TmpCell;  
      }  
 /*========displaying all clients in list==================*/  
 void Display( const head h )  
      {  
        addr a =h ;  
        if( h->next == NULL )  
      printf( "NO ONLINE CLIENTS\n" );  
        else  
        {  
           do  
           {  
             a = a->next;  
             printf( "%d->%s \t", a->port,a->username );  
           } while( a->next != NULL );  
           printf( "\n" );  
        }  
      }  
 /*===========client deleted from list if client quits================*/  
 void Delete( int port, head h ){  
        addr a, TmpCell;  
        a = h;  
    while( a->next != NULL && a->next->port != port )  
       a = a->next;  
   if( a->next != NULL ){             
      TmpCell = a->next;  
      a->next = TmpCell->next;   
      free( TmpCell );  
   }  
  }  
 /*======handling signals==========*/  
 void *Quitproc(){        
      printf("\n\nSERVER SHUTDOWN\n");  
      Quitall( );  
     exit(0);  
  }  
 /*===============notifying server shutdown===========*/  
 void Quitall(){  
   int sfd;  
   addr a = h ;  
   int i=0;  
    if( h->next == NULL ) {  
     printf( "......BYE.....\nno clients \n\n" );  
      exit(0);  
     } else {  
        do{  
          i++;  
         a = a->next;  
         sfd = a->port;  
         send(sfd,"server down",13,0);  
         } while( a->next != NULL );  
       printf("%d clients closed\n\n",i);         
       }  
  }  
 void zzz(){  
   printf("\rDISPLAYING ONLINE CLIENTS\n\n");  
   Display(h);  
  }  
 /*=====================================================================================================*/  

Here is the client program

 /* To compile me in Linux type: gcc -o client t2.c -lpthread*/  
 /* t2.c - code for client that uses TCP     */  
 /***CLIENT CODE*/  
 #include <stdio.h>  
 #include <stdlib.h>        
 #include <string.h>          //for string operations  
 #include <unistd.h>          //NULL constant defined here  
 #include <sys/types.h>            
 #include <sys/socket.h>          //for sockets  
 #include <netinet/in.h>          //Internet Protocol family sockaddr_in defined here   
 #include <pthread.h>          // for the cosy POSIX threads  
 #include <signal.h>          //for ctrl+c signal  
 #define MYPORT 2012     /* default port number */  
 #define MAXDATALEN 256  
 int      sockfd;  
 int      n,x;                         /*variables for socket*/  
 struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;          /* structure to hold server's address */  
 char      buffer[MAXDATALEN];  
 char      buf[10];            
 void *quitproc();  
 void* chat_write(int);  
 void* chat_read(int);  
 void *zzz();  
 /***************main starts************/  
 int main(int argc, char *argv[]){  
  pthread_t thr1,thr2;          /* variable to hold thread ID */  
     if( argc != 2 ){       
       printf("help:u need to put server ip\n");  
       exit(0);  
       }  
      /*=============socket creating==============*/  
      sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);  
      if (sockfd == -1)  
        printf ("client socket error\n");  
      else       
        printf("socket\t\tcreated\n");  
      /*===============set info===================*/  
      bzero((char *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr));  
      serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;  
      serv_addr.sin_port = htons(MYPORT);  
      serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr(argv[1]);  
      /*=========for username=====================*/  
      bzero(buf,10);  
      printf("\nENTER YOUR NAME::");  
      fgets(buf,10,stdin);  
      __fpurge(stdin);       
      buf[strlen(buf)-1]=':';  
      /*=============client connect to server============*/  
      if(connect(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *) &serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr))==-1)  
      {  
        printf("client connect error\n");  
        exit(0);  
      }  
      else  
        printf("%s connected to server\n",buf);  
      printf("\rYOU JOINED AS- %s",buffer-1);  
      send(sockfd,buf,strlen(buf),0);  
      pthread_create(&thr2,NULL,(void *)chat_write,(void *)sockfd);     //thread creation for writing  
      pthread_create(&thr1,NULL,(void *)chat_read,(void *)sockfd);     //thread creation for reading  
      pthread_join(thr2,NULL);  
      pthread_join(thr1,NULL);  
      return 0;  
 } /*main ends*/  
 /*======================================================================*/  
 /*======reading continously from socket=============*/  
 void* chat_read(int sockfd)  
 {  
      if (signal(SIGINT,(void *)quitproc)==0)  
      if(signal(SIGTSTP, (void *)zzz)==0)  
      while(1)  
      {  
        n=recv(sockfd,buffer,MAXDATALEN-1,0);  
         if(n==0){   
            printf("\nDUE TO SOME UNEXPECTED REASONS SERVER HAS BEEN SHUTDOWN\n\n");  
             exit(0);  
             }  
         if(n>0){  
              printf("\n%s ",buffer);  
            bzero(buffer,MAXDATALEN);  
             }  
      }//while ends  
 }  
 /*======writing continously to socket=============*/  
 void* chat_write(int sockfd)  
 {  
      while(1)  
      {  
        printf("%s",buf);  
          fgets(buffer,MAXDATALEN-1,stdin);  
         if(strlen(buffer)-1>sizeof(buffer)){  
             printf("buffer size full\t enter within %d characters\n",sizeof(buffer));  
             bzero(buffer,MAXDATALEN);  
             __fpurge(stdin);  
             }  
        n=send(sockfd,buffer,strlen(buffer),0);  
         if(strncmp(buffer,"quit",4)==0)  
             exit(0);  
         bzero(buffer,MAXDATALEN);  
      }//while ends  
 }  
 /*======handling signals==========*/  
 void *quitproc(){            //handling ctrl+d  
    printf("\rPLEASE TYPE 'quit' TO EXIT\n");  
 }  
 void *zzz(){               //handling ctrl+z  
    printf("\rPLEASE TYPE 'quit' TO EXIT\n");  
 }  
 /*=================================================================*/
```

Comment: "I am unable to add another feature to my program " Why?

Comment: Yes please provide more information.

Comment: @sufian what else information u need?

Comment: Check what @Epodax said.

Comment: Because i am not familiar with these commands SO_RECVTIMEO and dont know how and where to use in my program

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the socket options SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO at your call to setsockopt() at the server side. Thus, the TCP stack terminates any connection over this socket if it is inactive for the specified timeout.

It may/should then be the case that the blocking call to recv() in the server() function (i.e. your server's client thread) will then unblock with an error, but as I recall the exact behaviour may be OS-dependent.
Otherwise, you would need to cyclically check any open fd for being "reachable" from yet another monitoring thread, e.g. by sending a small status message. (That thread's cycle time must then of course be higher than the configured timeout, otherwise you would keep the connection alive in any case by cyclically sending the message.)

Once you've detected that the connection was closed, you could do any necessary error/cleanup handling in the server's client thread before it terminates.

If you also want to initiate a connection shutdown from the client side, use the function shutdown() there, which should also tell the corresponding (blocking) recv() call on the server to unblock with an error.

Comment: I suppose OP wants to close idle connections not necessarily lost/unreachable cllients. `TCP KEEPALIVE` would give positive results if the server and client do not exchange data. But line will be idle at application level.

Comment: I have to apologize, in my first version of the post I was mentioning SO_KEEPALIVE. In fact, I meant the SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO options, as suggested in your answer above.

Comment: @user3567678 can you please tell me at what line in server code i should use SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO commands? should it be in while code? Since i am not familiar with these commands...Secondly do i need to add any other library on server?

Comment: You could use these commands the same way you are using SO_REUSEADDR. Use the code snippet Prabhu provided in his post above and adapt it to your needs.
As for the library question, I don't think you need any additional library, but that may be OS dependent.

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using blocking sockets.

In thread function `server` you are in `while(1)` doing `recv` on client sockets. If `recv` returns zero or client sends in "quit" message you close the socket `ts_fd` and inform other clients.

You can use the `SO_RCVTIMEO` capability (setting socket option with `setsockopt`)  to put timeout on `recv` calls. If no data is available for `recv` to give to the application in specified time, `recv` would return EGAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK. You can treat this as client being idle and close the connection.

```
struct timeval tv;

tv.tv_sec = 30;  /* 30 Secs Timeout */
tv.tv_usec = 0;  

setsockopt(sockfd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, (char *)&tv,sizeof(struct timeval));
```

Comment: Dear prabhuu, thank u for your help. Can you please help me where should i add these commands in server program?

Comment: can you please tell me at what line in server code i should use SO_RCVTIMEO and SO_SNDTIMEO commands? should it be in while code? Since i am not familiar with these commands...Secondly do i need to add any other library on server?

Comment: Those are not commands. Once the server accepts connection 'accept' call, you call the 'setsockopt' on new sd as seen in my post. Before that define the timer values also shown in the post.

Comment: i have tried to add the said commands but i am facing errors and code is not working. Please help me out.